# Terraform aws retrieve target group and associated load balancer arn suffix

Tags: terraform, amazon-cloudwatch, terraform-provider-aws, cloudwatch-alarms

I'm trying to create a standaloone terraform CloudWatch module for various alarms, including one that measures `unhealthyhostcount`. Most of the alarms have one dimension, but, unfortunately, this one requires both the TargetGroup and the associated LoadBalancer, and I cannot devise a way of extracting this from the data sources. Has anyone managed to create a terraform CloudWatch alarm based on this metric?

The resource is very straightforward:

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "target_group_unhealthy_hosts_alarms" 

  alarm_name          = "target-group-unhealthy-hosts-alarm"
  comparison_operator = "GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold"
  evaluation_periods  = 5
  metric_name         = "UnHealthyHostCount"
  namespace           = "AWS/ApplicationELB"
  period              = 300
  statistic           = "Average"
  threshold           = 5
  actions_enabled     = true
  alarm_description   = "Alarm when there are at least five unhealthy hosts in the target group."
  dimensions = {
    LoadBalancer = var.loadbalaner
    TargetGroup  = var.targetgroup
  }
  alarm_actions = local.sns_topic_arn
}
```